# Cross-site scripting (DOM-based) burp issues

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, burp

In Burp Scanner Report, I got below issue

The application may be vulnerable to DOM-based cross-site scripting. Data is read from location and passed to $() via the following statement:

```
     $(location).attr('href',"/MYAPP/home.action");
```

How this can be avoided. Will below solution to prepend '/' work in this case or it will be still exploitable

```
     $(location).attr('href','/'+"MYAPP/home.action");
```

Comment: It’s likely a false positive that can’t be exploited.  See the last paragraph under [description](https://portswigger.net/kb/issues/00200310_cross-site-scripting-dom-based)

Comment: @James so prepending '/' will work and this issue will not be reported in re-test using burp ?

Comment: Some issues caught using burp or other testing tool have to be looked at by the developer who checks the code and says “no this is not a problem” and that’s the end of it.  Trying to clean up false positives is usually a waste of time.